# Получение GET запроса

Tags: java, android

Решил освоить Android, но на первых парах столкнулся с такой проблемой. 


Есть метод, который по задумке, должен получать `JSON` строку с сайта:

```
protected String getJson() throws Exception{

    URL url = new URL("http://h92761ae.beget.tech/json_current_parameters_hum.php");

    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();

    return response.toString();

}
```

Вызываю так:

```
    String json;

    try{
        json = getJson();
    } catch(Exception e){}
```

Но при просмотре в дебагере, код выдаёт исключение в этой строчке:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
```

Что я делаю не так?

**UPD**

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
>   at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
>   at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
>   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752) at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:187)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:156)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:98)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:345)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
>   at com.dmepty.jsonparse.MainActivity.getJson(MainActivity.java:39) at
>   com.dmepty.jsonparse.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Comment: желательно видеть ошибку, ваш код рабочий 
[{"id":"2","id_parameter":"5","id_device":"1","code_parameter":"paramHumidityValue","value":"29","date":"2018-05-04 14:25:27"}]

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Ошибки как таковой нет, просто после указанной строчки выполнение продолжается в блоке `catch`. Возможно я не правильно высказался.

Comment: @dmepty Ну так дампните экскепшн: e.printStackTrace(); и смотрите logcat. Какой дурак вообще пустые catch оставляет?

Comment: блок try catch сделан для того чтоб отлавливать исключения, вот то что попало в catch e.printStackTrace() и надо в вопрос добавить

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Обновил, это то, что нужно?

Comment: ну да канеш, вот и первая строчка ваш ответ.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Получается, этот метод нужно запускать в отдельном потоке?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Благодарю, и ещё последний вопрос, всегда ли исключение показывается в первой строке в Logcat?

Comment: Зависит от многих фактов но ответ -> Нет, но для это существуют куча tools, это очень большой вопрос. Для начала я бы советовал, не оставлять пустыми try catch, и даже больше просто ставить Asserts и тогда программа завершиться на месте RuntimeException и вы сможете быстрей локализовать причину падения. Прошу учесть что такой вариант далеко не самый верный, но для отладки в начальном этапе, мне кажется самый простой, быстрый и подходящий

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Ещё раз спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Android запрещает делать сетевые операции на MainThread.*

**Решение:**

1. Вы можете делать ваш вызов в отдельном потоке любым удобным способом. Threads, AsyncTask, IntentService, Rx. Я советую использовать [Retrofit2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
2. StrictMode отключить такое поведение. (не рекомендую)

Подробно есть в документациях: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException